# Decode json output to a model

Tags: json, swift, swift4, codable

I have this json output that I want to parse using Codable:

```
{
"success": true,
"total": 1,
"users": [
    {
        "user": {
            "id": "1",
            "fname": "admin",
            "lname": "admin",
            "login": "admin",
            "actif": "0",
            "last_connection_date": "2018-01-18 16:02:34"
        }
    }
],
"msg": ""
}
```

And I just want to exctact the user's informations out of it.
My user's model

```
import RealmSwift

class User: Object, Codable {

@objc dynamic var id: String = ""
@objc dynamic var fname: String = ""
@objc dynamic var lname: String = ""
@objc dynamic var login: String = ""

//    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
//        case id = "users[0].user.id"
//        case fname = "users[0].user.fname"
//        case lname = "users[0].lname"
//        case login = "users[0].user.login"
//        case password = "users[0].user.password"
//    }

}

// Somewhere in my code
Alamofire.request(Path.userInformations(id: userId).rawValue).
responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
       do {
            let user = try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: response.data!)
            } catch (let error) {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
       })
```

I've tried extracting the user's object, but wasn't successful casting it to `Data` to feed it to `JSONDecoder().decode()` method.

## Responding to Vishal16 's comment

I've tried you first approach. It does not seem to work because, I think, of keyword "user" before the user's object. I've tried adding a new struct that wrap the user's object, but does not solve it.

```
struct ResponseBody : Codable {
   var success : Bool?
   var total : Int?
   var users : [UserHolder]?
   var msg : String?
   var query_start : String?
   var query_end : String?
   var query_time : String?
   var paging : Bool?
}

struct UserHolder : Codable {
    var user: User?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case user = "user"

    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        user = try values.decodeIfPresent(User.self, forKey: .user)
    }
}
```

Comment: Will need more context than that. Can you share the code around the line  `JSONDecoder().decode()`?

Comment: @Malik I've updated my initial post with more context (a simple Alamofire get request)

Comment: What does it print in `error.localizedDescription`

Comment: Based on your provided information, the `user` container in your `JSON` is two levels down. But in your code, you are passing the complete json to a decoder that expects the json to only have the `user` container

Comment: @UmairAamir `The data couldn’t be read because it is missing`

Comment: @Malik Is there a way to tell it to go two levels down ? I've tried parsing the json as a dictionnary then casting to `Data`, and then feeding it to the `JSONDecoder().decode()` method, but didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your response class structure should be like:

```
import Foundation
struct ResponseBody : Codable {
var status : Bool?
var total : Int?
var users : [User]? //list of users 
var msg : String?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

    case status = "status"
    case total = "total"
    case users = "users"
    case msg = "msg"
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    status = try values.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: . status)
    total = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: . total)
    users = try values.decodeIfPresent([User].self, forKey: . users)
    msg = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: . msg)
}
}
```

Now you will able to retrive your JSON data to object

```
let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
let response = try jsonDecoder.decode(ResponseBody.self, from: data)

for user in response.users {
   // user object is here
}
```

**#edit**

If you do not want to parse full response to JSON object

1. First convert Data to JSON Object using

   let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! Dictionary
2. Get users list string JSON then convert it to Data and after that data to User List object

   if let responseBody = jsonResponse["users"] {

   let dataBody = (responseBody as! String).data(using: .utf8)!
   if let obj = Utils.convertToArray(data: dataBody) {
      print(obj) // list of user obj
   }
   }

Hear is the method using in above implementation

```
class func convertToArray(data: Data) -> [AnyObject]? {
    do {
        return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [AnyObject]
    } catch {
        Constants.print(items: error.localizedDescription)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Hope this help you. Happy codding :)

**So hear is the working code for you**
It's just working fine in my Playground. Please see below screenshots

1.[image]

2.[image]

3.[image]

**Decode json output to a model**

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Please seed my response in the initial post :)

Comment: Okay, wait a minute.

Comment: The problem was, I had `int` instead of `string` for user's id  . Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 0):

```
class User: Object, Codable {

@objc dynamic var id: String = ""
@objc dynamic var fname: String = ""
@objc dynamic var lname: String = ""
@objc dynamic var login: String = ""

}

class Users: Object, Codable {

@objc dynamic var users: [User]

}
```

And for decoding

```
let user = try JSONDecoder().decode(Users.self, from: response.data!)
```

I think it should resolve the issue.

The other way is, you have to convert your `response.data` to `Dictionary` to dig down to `user` object.